# Powershell: Start-Transcript to just log the commands and not results

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to make start-transcript log just the commands and not the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible now. Here is the suggestion for the version next: [add Start-Transcript filters](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/611703/add-start-transcript-filters)

Comment: Alternatively override Function:prompt and add a line that gets history command of the last command that was run, eg `(H -count 1).CommandLine`. Because Prompt is run after the previous command completes it should be possible to get only the latest command, and dump it out to a file.

Answer (score 3):

This was a powershell.com tip of the day recently:

When you run Start-Transcript, PowerShell will document all console input and output in a file. To remove all output and create a file with your PowerShell commands only, you should use this piece of code:

```
$path = "$home\Documents\allcommands.txt"

dir $home\Documents\*transc* |
    ForEach-Object { Get-Content $_.FullName  } |
        ForEach-Object { if ($_ -match '^PS.*?>') {
            $_.SubString($matches[0].Length).Trim()
        }
    } |
        Where-Object { $_ } |
            Out-File $path

Invoke-Item $path
```